# GeoServer GeoWebCache non-default Styles

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, javascript, geowebcache, tile-map-service

I have a tile layer on GeoServer with a default gray style. I want to be able to serve this tile layer as a GeoWebCache with a colored style (not default).

I enabled the caching defaults to "Automatically cache non-default styles" and have attempted to add the data to a leaflet map, specifying the style needed:

```
L.tileLayer(`${GeoServerUrl}/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/{Workspace}%3A${layerName}@EPSG%3A900913@png/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`, {
    zIndex: 100,
    tms:true,
    opacity: 1.0,
    className: 'layer1',
    styles: 'colored_style_name' //non-default style name
  }).addTo(map);
```

This does not work. I'm wondering if there is a way to serve the data via GeoWebCache TMS with a different style other than the default - or to do this would I need to serve it as a completely new tile layer on Geoserver and set the new style as default?

Comment: what does not work? do you get an error? a style you don't expect? something else? what does the log file say? why not change the default style?

Comment: It doesn't display the layer at all when I specify the new style. The default style is currently being used another map.

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Also, does your new style work in layer preview?